# Wordpress how to disable overflow

Tags: php, wordpress

i have created a modal in wordpress using this code on a custom snippet and displaying it using a shortcode on wordpress.

```
echo" <img id='gallery-pic' src='$image_src'>

    <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
      <span class='close'>×</span>
      <img class='modal-content' id='img01'>
      <div id='caption'></div>
    </div>

 <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


    var img = document.getElementById('gallery-pic');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
    img.onclick = function(){
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      modal.style.display = 'block';
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;

    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
    </script> ";
 ?>
```

the document.body.style.overflow doesn't work on wordpress but if i switch "overflow" to "backgroundColor='yellow'" it works. How can i remove the overflow of the main page once i open the modal?

Comment: Are you sure the body element is the thing that's scrolling? Isn't there a wrapper or something like that in which you are scrolling? Overflow hidden as you wrote it should work if the body is the one in which you're scrolling.

Comment: just realized its the HTML tag that needs to be hidden not body

Comment: Does that solves your problem? You can access the HTML element by using document.documentElement

Comment: yes it does. Thankyou!